# Read XML data into hierarchical tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xquery, sqlxml

I have XML data that is used to store quiz results.  I need to convert this into two tables, one containing the questions, and the other containing the answers, but crucially, have a relation between them.

Currently this relation only exists in the XML structure (there are no ID values, etc.).

After a day of research and testing out different approaches, I've got as far as extracting the two parts, but cannot figure out how to create the hierarchy:

```
declare @xml xml = N'<quizresult>
  <question>
    <questionText>Which fire extinguisher is most suitable for a waste paper basket fire?</questionText>
    <answer number="0" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Powder</answer>
    <answer number="1" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Carbon Dioxide (CO2)</answer>
    <answer number="2" value="1" chosen="1" imageURL="">Water (H2O)</answer>
    <answer number="3" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Foam</answer>
    <result>Correct</result>
  </question>
  <question>
    <questionText>What should your immediate action be on hearing a fire alarm?</questionText>
    <answer number="0" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Find all of your colleagues before making a speedy exit together</answer>
    <answer number="1" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Collect all your valuables before making a speedy exit</answer>
    <answer number="2" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Check the weather to see if you need your coat before leaving</answer>
    <answer number="3" value="1" chosen="1" imageURL="">Leave the building by the nearest exit, closing doors behind you if the rooms are empty</answer>
    <result>Correct</result>
  </question>
  <question>
    <questionText>Which is the most suitable extinguisher for a Computer which is on fire?</questionText>
    <answer number="0" value="0" chosen="1" imageURL="">Water (H2O)</answer>
    <answer number="1" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Powder</answer>
    <answer number="2" value="1" chosen="0" imageURL="">Carbon Dioxide (CO2)</answer>
    <result>Incorrect</result>
  </question>
</quizresult>';

-- Get questions only

DECLARE @questions TABLE (questionText nvarchar(max), result nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO @questions (questionText, result)
SELECT
    n.q.value('(./questionText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS questionText,
    n.q.value('(./result)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS result
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/quizresult/question') AS n (q);

-- Get answers only

DECLARE @answers TABLE (answer nvarchar(max), number int, val int, chosen bit);
INSERT INTO @answers (answer, number, val, chosen)
SELECT
    n.q.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS answer,
    n.q.value('@number', 'int') AS number,
    n.q.value('@value', 'int') AS val,
    n.q.value('@chosen', 'bit') AS chosen
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/quizresult/question/answer') AS n (q);
```

Can anyone please enlighten me if it is possible to create IDs/GUID's (or something) to create the parent/child hierarchy that respects the XML file?
  I should add, in actual fact this is an XML column and the data will be transformed en-masse.  I'm just using a variable until I figure out the basic approach.

Comment: I think the only possibility will be to join the questions and answers using the answer text. But in this case the question must be unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can (ab)use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate the IDs outside XQuery. Preamble:

```
WITH questions AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ID,
        n.q.value('(./questionText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS questionText,
        n.q.value('(./result)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS result,
        n.q.query('answer') AS answers
    FROM
        @xml.nodes('/quizresult/question') AS n (q)
), questions_and_answers AS (
    SELECT ID, questionText, result, answer.query('.') AS answer
    FROM questions
    CROSS APPLY answers.nodes('answer') AS a(answer)
)
```

And now retrieve the questions with

```
SELECT ID, questionText, result 
FROM questions
```

And the answers with

```
SELECT ID AS questionID,
    q.answer.value('answer[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS answer,
    q.answer.value('answer[1]/@number', 'int') AS number,
    q.answer.value('answer[1]/@value', 'int') AS val,
    q.answer.value('answer[1]/@chosen', 'bit') AS chosen
FROM questions_and_answers AS q
```

Comment: I really like this approach thanks.  The problem is I would ideally require both questions and answers (both your examples), but because the CTE's are only used once, I have to run the query twice, which is expensive.  Is there a way to get both tables without running the XML query multiple times?

Comment: @EvilDr: you could store `questions_and_answers` in a temp table first, then query on that (getting the questions with a `DISTINCT`). It's not possible to insert two tables at the same time with one query, so no matter how you slice it, some intermediate is required. (Unless you use cursors, but the performance drawback of row-by-row processing will probably negate any benefits of that.)

Comment: Okay no problem.  My main reservation was the amount of duplicate questions in there (one per answer), which I hoped might be avoided.

Comment: If your XML is truly enormous, so that shredding/denormalizing it is the bottleneck, and you expected a big ratio between parent and child rows (not very likely with questions and answers, but it might occur in general), it would be worthwhile to look into either cursors to loop over questions (while keeping the answer inserts table-based) or client-side processing of XML (which is not restricted to set-based approaches like SQL is). I'm reluctant to work out either approach in my answer, but those are options.

Comment: No, that's fine.  I appreciate the help you've provided, and will accept the answer.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could now help me migrate this logic to apply to every row in a table, rather than a single xml value (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938720/select-row-data-in-addition-to-structured-xml-data) please.

Answer (score 2):

By using `MERGE` to insert your questions, you can capture fields from both the source and target data. So you can then access both the newly inserted question ID, and the corresponding answers and remove the need to rely on question text to link questions to answers.

You just need a mapping table to store the intermediate results after inserting questions.

```
DECLARE @Mapping TABLE (QuestionID INT NOT NULL, Answers XML);

MERGE @questions AS q
USING
(   SELECT  questionText = q.x.value('questionText[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
            result = q.x.value('result[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
            Answers = q.x.query('answer')
    FROM    @xml.nodes('quizresult/question') q (x)
) AS t
    ON 1 = 0 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (QuestionText, Result)
    VALUES (t.QuestionText, t.Result)
OUTPUT inserted.QuestionID, t.Answers INTO @Mapping (QuestionID, Answers);
```

Then having stored the intermediate results, including the question ID, you can query the mapping table to insert the answers.

```
-- INSERT ANSWERS USING MAPPING TABLE
INSERT @Answers (QuestionID, Answer, Number, Val, Chosen)
SELECT  m.QuestionID,
        answer = a.x.value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        number = a.x.value('@number[1]', 'INT'),
        val = a.x.value('@value[1]', 'INT'),
        chosen = a.x.value('@chosen[1]', 'BIT')
FROM    @Mapping m
        CROSS APPLY Answers.nodes('answer') a (x);
```

**Full working Demo**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<quizresult>
  <question>
    <questionText>Which fire extinguisher is most suitable for a waste paper basket fire?</questionText>
    <answer number="0" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Powder</answer>
    <answer number="1" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Carbon Dioxide (CO2)</answer>
    <answer number="2" value="1" chosen="1" imageURL="">Water (H2O)</answer>
    <answer number="3" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Foam</answer>
    <result>Correct</result>
  </question>
  <question>
    <questionText>What should your immediate action be on hearing a fire alarm?</questionText>
    <answer number="0" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Find all of your colleagues before making a speedy exit together</answer>
    <answer number="1" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Collect all your valuables before making a speedy exit</answer>
    <answer number="2" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Check the weather to see if you need your coat before leaving</answer>
    <answer number="3" value="1" chosen="1" imageURL="">Leave the building by the nearest exit, closing doors behind you if the rooms are empty</answer>
    <result>Correct</result>
  </question>
  <question>
    <questionText>Which is the most suitable extinguisher for a Computer which is on fire?</questionText>
    <answer number="0" value="0" chosen="1" imageURL="">Water (H2O)</answer>
    <answer number="1" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Powder</answer>
    <answer number="2" value="1" chosen="0" imageURL="">Carbon Dioxide (CO2)</answer>
    <result>Incorrect</result>
  </question>
  <question>
    <questionText>Which is the most suitable extinguisher for a Computer which is on fire?</questionText>
    <answer number="0" value="0" chosen="1" imageURL="">Water (H2O) DUPLICATE</answer>
    <answer number="1" value="0" chosen="0" imageURL="">Powder DUPLICATE</answer>
    <answer number="2" value="1" chosen="0" imageURL="">Carbon Dioxide (CO2) DUPLICATE</answer>
    <result>Incorrect</result>
  </question>
</quizresult>';

-- DEMO TARGE TABLES
DECLARE @questions TABLE 
(
    QuestionID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    questionText NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    result NVARCHAR(50)
);
DECLARE @answers TABLE 
(
    AnswerID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    QuestionID INT NOT NULL,
    answer NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    number INT, 
    val INT, 
    chosen BIT
);



-- MAPPING TABLE
DECLARE @Mapping TABLE (QuestionID INT NOT NULL, Answers XML);

-- INSERT ANSWERS
MERGE @questions AS q
USING
(   SELECT  questionText = q.x.value('questionText[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
            result = q.x.value('result[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
            Answers = q.x.query('answer')
    FROM    @xml.nodes('quizresult/question') q (x)
) AS t
    ON 1 = 0 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (QuestionText, Result)
    VALUES (t.QuestionText, t.Result)
OUTPUT inserted.QuestionID, t.Answers INTO @Mapping (QuestionID, Answers);

-- INSERT ANSWERS USING MAPPING TABLE
INSERT @Answers (QuestionID, Answer, Number, Val, Chosen)
SELECT  m.QuestionID,
        answer = a.x.value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        number = a.x.value('@number[1]', 'INT'),
        val = a.x.value('@value[1]', 'INT'),
        chosen = a.x.value('@chosen[1]', 'BIT')
FROM    @Mapping m
        CROSS APPLY Answers.nodes('answer') a (x);

-- CHECK RESULTS
SELECT  *
FROM    @Questions AS q
        INNER JOIN @Answers AS a
            ON a.QuestionID = q.QuestionID;
```

Comment: Please see my comments for @Rex's answer about matching on questionText.  Is this solution susceptible to the same (highly unlikely, but possible) risk?

Comment: Nope. I have just edited the working example so that there is a duplicate question in there to show that it still works.

Answer (score 1):

The only relationship here is with questionText. Hence this column can be fetched like this

```
DECLARE @answers TABLE (questionText nvarchar(max),answer nvarchar(max), 
number int, val int, chosen bit);

INSERT INTO @answers (questionText, answer, number, val, chosen)
SELECT
n.q.value('(../questionText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as questionText,
n.q.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS answer,
n.q.value('@number', 'int') AS number,
n.q.value('@value', 'int') AS val,
n.q.value('@chosen', 'bit') AS chosen
FROM
@xml.nodes('/quizresult/question/answer') AS n (q);
```

Alternatively, you can have ID generated based on questionText

```
DECLARE @questions TABLE (Id int, questionText nvarchar(max), result nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @questions (id, questionText, result)
SELECT
    Rank() over(order by n.q.value('(./questionText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) as Id,
    n.q.value('(./questionText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS questionText,
    n.q.value('(./result)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS result
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/quizresult/question') AS n (q);

DECLARE @answers TABLE (Id int, questionText nvarchar(max),answer 
nvarchar(max), number int, val int, chosen bit);

INSERT INTO @answers (Id, questionText, answer, number, val, chosen)
SELECT
   Dense_rank() over(order by n.q.value('(../questionText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) as Id,
   n.q.value('(../questionText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as questionText,
   n.q.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS answer,
   n.q.value('@number', 'int') AS number,
   n.q.value('@value', 'int') AS val,
   n.q.value('@chosen', 'bit') AS chosen
FROM
   @xml.nodes('/quizresult/question/answer') AS n (q);
```

Other solution would be if same question/answer could repeat

```
DECLARE @questions TABLE (Id int identity(1,1), questionText nvarchar(max), result nvarchar(50), answer xml);
INSERT INTO @questions ( questionText, result, answer)
SELECT
n.q.value('(./questionText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS questionText,
n.q.value('(./result)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS result,
 n.q.query('answer') AS answer
FROM
@xml.nodes('/quizresult/question') AS n (q);

DECLARE @answers TABLE (Id int, questionText nvarchar(max),answer nvarchar(max), number int, val int, chosen bit);
INSERT INTO @answers (Id, questionText, answer, number, val, chosen)
SELECT
q.Id as Id,
q.questionText as questionText,
n.q.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS answer,
n.q.value('@number', 'int') AS number,
n.q.value('@value', 'int') AS val,
n.q.value('@chosen', 'bit') AS chosen
FROM
@questions q
 outer apply q.answer.nodes('answer') as n(q)

select * from @questions
select * from @answers
```

Comment: The danger of joining on questionText is that there is a possibility (highly unlikely, but still possible), that the same question text can exist twice in a quiz.  Therefore I was hoping to generate an ID at question-level that didn't rely on a text match...

Comment: What about answers? Could that be same for the each questions that repeats?

Comment: Yes.  Again, its rediculously unlikely, but *could* happen in theory.